# Using off vs. one Jquery function with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying through clicking a button to turn off completely a jquery css animation which is dependent on mousemove and then show another html element. I was able to produce the show action, but turning off hasn't been possible. As I only want to use the jquery css animation once and then that's it, I think either - one jquery method or a on/off jquery function would do it. I think I should put the one jquery method before setTimeout, but I'm not 100% where it should go. Researching and observing what others were doing I've come a bit closer:

```
$(document).on('mousemove',(function (event) {});
});
),6300);
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button__next').click(function(){
$(document).off('mousemove');
$('#buble2.buble__conainer').show();
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oekhedr/qfnkLz76/#&togetherjs=4Bsp9CVtlB

Thank you so much

Comment: .one is for binding an event. you didn't provide an event type or even a callback in your sample code... not making much sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kevin sir, my function is below my settimeout function. Apologies I'm pretty new to coding

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Please include *all* relevant code **in the question itself**.

Comment: zzzzBov apologies for that. I just put in all the relevant code that I'm aware of in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qfnkLz76/9/

setTimeout is unnecessary, on/off is the correct approach.

**on:** Attach event

**off:** Detach event

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function (event) {...

$('body').off('mousemove');
```

In order to makes mousemove works on body it should have the window height, so I add this code to the css:

```
html,
body {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Please read more about jQuery and Javascript to understand how to work with it.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your help

Comment: You are welcome Omar, please if it work's for you accept the answer as correct.